# Stored Procedure -- Invalid Column Name on WHERE clause

Tags: stored-procedures

I am creating a stored procedure for a cascading dropdown list, via Microsoft's Visual Web Developer's database explorer, and i'm getting an Invalid Column Name error when running the procedure. I have tried recreating the database table and renaming the column, but I get the same error no matter what the column name is.

This is how the procedure looks...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetEquipmentByVendorID @VendorID INT
AS 
    BEGIN
        SELECT  EquipmentModel
        FROM    Equipment
        WHERE   VendorID = @VendorID
    END
```

The error occurs on the WHERE clause.

I have read through other posts about this error, but i've found nothing that resolves the issue. Any assistance you can provide is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your table's structure? And just to clarify: you're getting the error when you're creating the procedure or when you're trying to run it?

Comment: The error occurs when attempting to create it. The table structure is simple: There are only two columns. First column name is VendorID and the second is Vendor.

Comment: You mean Equipment doesn't have a column named EquipmentModel? There's your trouble, then.

Comment: Apologies...there are two tables. One called "Vendors" which has the two columns that I mentioned. The second table is called "Equipment" and has three columns, EquipmentID, EquipmentModel, and EquipID. From the Equipment table, I only need data from the EquipmentModel column

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments, the reason your sp's compilation fails is straightforward: you are missing the requisite column. Add the `VendorID` to your `Equipment` table and you shouldn't have problems anymore.

Comment: you're welcome! A final thought: please mark my answer as the correct one